# change active li when clicking a link jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a menu, and change the class when clicking.

When i click on the "li" with no `class="active"`, i want jquery to add a class on the empty `<li>`  and remove it from the othes "li".

```
<li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.data.load(1);">data</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.data.load(2);">data 2</a></li>
```

can somebody help me ? :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
$('li > a').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 15):

```
// When we click on the LI
$("li").click(function(){
  // If this isn't already active
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    // Remove the class from anything that is active
    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
    // And make this active
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('li').click(function()
{
    $('li', $(this).parent()).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    page=window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
    menuChildren = $('a[href="' + page + '"]');  
    $(menuChildren).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

The above code will look up the url and pop out the last element (Which is the file name). Then it finds the anchor tag with `href` attribute which has the same value of the url then it puts an active class for its parent `li` tag

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close.

```
$("li").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```