# jquery list, keep active highlighted

Tags: jquery, css, listview, drop-down-menu

I figured out a new way to do my list, but am having a couple issues with it... 
here's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/mstngsal67/GuE99/5/
I'm trying to understand why the left menu item, when clicked, only remains bold if i am hovering over it...if i move away, it changes back.  i have tried a lot of different things in the css but nothing has worked...  do i need to do this in js instead???
here is part of my code, but going to the jsfiddle has everything...

```
<ul class="mainMenus"> 
<li onclick='showSubMenu("sm_item1")'>education 
      <ul class="subMenus" id="sm_item1" style="top:0px"> 
             <li><a href="careers.html"class="text7">careers</a></li> 
             <li><a href="careers.html"class="text7">careers</a></li> 
             <li><a href="careers.html"class="text7">careers</a></li> 
             <li><a href="careers.html"class="text7">careers</a></li> 
      </ul>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: there's no way you can do it only by css.
the hover is a pseudo that only applies when you hover the element.
if you want it to maintain the hover properties you can add a js snipped that adds a class with the same hover properties, something like this:
    $('.mainMenus li').click(function(){
$('.selected').removeClass('selected'); 
$(this).addClass('selected')
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make another CSS class, and toggle it on and off (using jQuery) when the li element is active or not.

Try looking here:

[change active li when clicking a link jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343178/change-active-li-when-clicking-a-link-jquery)

Comment: either i'm not bright enough to figure this out (which is probably the case) or it isn't working how i was hoping...  i added the css class .active with the properties i wanted...  and changed my code to this <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('li > a').click(function() {$('li').removeClass(); $(this).parent().addClass('active');});">education</a>

Comment: Here's a working jfiddle. Make sure you add the correct jQuery, and set up the "active" class in css. http://jsfiddle.net/GuE99/6/

Comment: before i post a new question - do you have thoughts on this...  i have added the bit of code we worked on to my overall scheme.  when clicking a submenu item, a lightbox pops up...  but it appears that when clicking on the link, it refreshes the screen so when one closes the lightbox, it goes back to the original look...  http://www.thendesign.com/new/type-test2.html

Comment: What is happening, is when you close the out of the lightbox, you're also clicking the ul "subMenus" (behind the lightbox) which is closing the list. I've removed your showmenu script from the header, and added a much more simple way of doing things with jQuery. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/GuE99/11/ Try adding that jFiddle code and see if it works. I changed some of the names of things so it would be more specific, so make sure to update the css as well. Lastly, you can delete the unnecessary calls to the showmenu on your "li" elements in the HTML as well (see jfiddle).

Comment: No problem, would you mark my response to your other question as correct? That way other people will know the answer is here as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The top level list item (e.g. Education) appears bold when it is hovered due to this line:

```
.mainMenus li:hover { 
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5e883c;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

It does not matter whether or not the list item was clicked -- as long as your mouse is hovered over the element, it will remain green and bold. Additionally, since your submenu lives within the top level list item, when you hover over the submenu, you are also hovering over the top level list item.

If you want your top level list item to be bold after the click, you will need to add a class name to the top level list item on your showSubMenu function.

Comment: i'm sorry, but, how do i add it to my showSubMenu function?  i don't know js well enough to figure that part out.  i'm still very new to this...