# don't refresh page when opening lightbox

Tags: onclick, refresh, lightbox

I have been working on setting up lists, changing pictures on hover, and lightbox on click.  it works mostly the way i want it save for one thing...  when i click on one of the submenus to open the lightbox, it appears to refresh the main page, thus going back to the default.
http://www.thendesign.com/new/type-test2.html
click on 'education' and then one of the projects to see what i am talking about.
how can i get it to remain where one left off when the lightbox opens/closes?
thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see this until after I had already responded to your comment over on your other question.

[jquery list, keep active highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316199/jquery-list-keep-active-highlighted)